# RPostgreSQL and DBI: "operator does not exist: uuid = text"

Tags: r, postgresql, postgis, r-dbi

When using `dbReadTable` to read in database tables that uses UUID as the primary key, I get the following warning message.

> 1: In postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) :
>     RS-DBI driver warning: (unrecognized PostgreSQL field type uuid (id:2950) in column 0)

When I modify the table I loaded and try to update the database using, I get the following error message:

> Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
>     RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  operator does not exist: uuid = text

*I get that the UUID type is not available in R, but is there a way that we can make the database believe the character vector "unique_id" is UUID instead of text?*

Code:

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(postGIStools)
pgdrv <- dbDriver(drvName = "PostgreSQL")

# === open connection
db <- DBI::dbConnect(pgdrv,
                     dbname="database",
                     host="localhost", port=5432,
                     user = 'postgres')

# === get tables
users <- dbReadTable(db, "app_users")

# === interaction with tables
users$employee_has_quit[1:5] <- TRUE

# === update tables
postgis_update(conn = db,
               df = users,
               tbl = "app_users",
               id_cols = "unique_id",
               update_cols = "employee_has_quit")

# === close conncetion
DBI::dbDisconnect(db)
```

Comment: Where is the error, in `dbReadTable` if so why are you pasting everything else below it? or are you getting the error in `postgis_update`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a bug in [postGIStools](https://github.com/SESYNC-ci/postGIStools). You can see the code they're using to [generate this error here](https://github.com/SESYNC-ci/postGIStools/blob/81149b677a41e88df71c43eddc06c22930999ff3/R/postgis_insert_update.R#L222)

```
query_text <- paste(query_text, ") AS", tbl_tmp, "(",
                    paste(quote_id(colnames(df)), collapse = ", "), ")",
                    "WHERE", paste(paste0(tbl_q, ".", id_q), "=",
                                   paste0(tbl_tmp, ".", id_q),
                                   collapse = " AND "))
```

Simply put, that won't work. They should be suing placeholders. It assumes that the [input type can be the result of `make_str_quote` (by proxy of `df_q` and `quote_str`)](https://github.com/SESYNC-ci/postGIStools/blob/81149b677a41e88df71c43eddc06c22930999ff3/R/postgis_insert_update.R#L203). That's a faulty assumption as seen here,

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( a uuid );
INSERT INTO foo VALUES ( quote_literal(gen_random_uuid()) ) ;

ERROR:  column "a" is of type uuid but expression is of type text
LINE 1: INSERT INTO foo VALUES ( quote_literal(gen_random_uuid()) ) ...
                                 ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

My suggestion is you follow the docs,

> Note: This package is deprecated. For new projects, we recommend using the [`sf`](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf) package to interface with geodatabases.

You may be able to work around [this by doing this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/177734/2639)

```
CREATE CAST (varchar AS uuid)
  WITH INOUT
  AS IMPLICIT;
```

Comment: Or, if you are using postgis with rasters, then the `rpostgis` package, works really well and is in active development ([https://github.com/mablab/rpostgis](https://github.com/mablab/rpostgis)).